# Qgis 2.18.1 text under a degree angle (Grass 7.0.5)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2.18, text, grass-7.0

I have a points layer with an attribute table with in one column the text (in this case streetnames) and in another column the angle in which the text should be to match the road (which is in another layer).

Is there a function in Qgis or a GrassTool to get my text in the right angle?

A screenshot from the relevant columns in my attribute table can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B04Y3.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You can find the option in the layer's properties label tab, you need to check 'Label this layer' at the top and choose your name field, then:

- Layer properties -> 'label' tab -> 'placement' tab
- click the icon next to 'rotation' and choose 'edit..'
- 'fields and values' dropdown -> select the field with your rotation values

Seeing your picture, I think you´d need to translate your rise/run values into degrees, you can either do that with an expression in the 'edit...' menu or by creating a new field using the field calculator.

(BTW: I freely translated QGIS' options names into English as I just have a german version right now...I am confident that you will find the right options though...)

Comment: let me add a suggestion: if you somehow have the possibility to join both tables, on a common attribute or by spatial relation, QGIS offers fairly intelligent line labeling with the text being auto orientated along the line features. this would avoid the transformation of your values, as I guess those are most likely in string format and you'd need to use regular expressions to do a conversion to degrees. might be worth a thought...